# Upgrade Jmeter to 3.2 using homebrew

Tags: jmeter, homebrew

I currently have jmeter 3.1 installed with homebrew, however would like to upgrade it to version 3.2.

I've tried to `brew upgrade jmeter` but it returns with the error

> jmeter 3.1 is already installed

I've got a work around by having version 3.2 downloaded and then launch it by navigating into the folder, but I'd like to have the homebrew version up to date if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [braumeister.org](http://braumeister.org/formula/jmeter) current JMeter version on homebrew is 3.1. It means nobody updated it yet. You can

- Wait for them to update it
- As [FAQ](http://docs.brew.sh/FAQ.html) explains, edit jmeter formula by yourself:

> Just `brew edit <formula>`. You don’t have to submit modifications back to homebrew/core, just edit the formula as you personally need it and brew install. As a bonus brew update will merge your changes with upstream so you can still keep the formula up-to-date with your personal modifications!

- Or commit an update to [jmeter.rb](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/jmeter.rb) to include 3.2 and see if they accept your change